# PhpStorm formatting, chopped down line indent after context

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatting, phpstorm

Our team will start to use a formatter for PHP. We decided the easiest way was to use an already existing standard and decided for PSR-12.

Half the team uses VSCode and the extension Intelephense for formatting.
The other half uses PhpStorm and the built in formatter with the PSR-12 preset.

Some modifications had to be made in PhpStorm to behave the same as the VSCode formatter. This because the VSCode extension requires Premium to change formatting preferences.

However there is one problem remaining.

PhpStorm indents a wrapped line after context, do not know how else to describe it. As can be seen in the snippet below there are 8 spaces before the string in the array and 4 spaces before the closing bracket.

```php
if (1 && [
        'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    ]) {
}
```

If I remove the first argument (`1`) the indentation becomes correct

```php
if ([
     'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
]) {
}
```

When formatting with VSCode, this is the result

```php
if (1 && [
     'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
]) {
}
```

I have read through the PhpStorm formatting settings multiple times and been searching the web for similar problems but I am nowhere closer to fixing this.

Am I missing a setting or do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure about this at all (what might be causing it). I have put your code sample into the Preview area of the Code Style for PHP in PhpStorm (yes, you can use your own code sample for that) and was clicking different options ... but the formatting remains (as I understand there is no option that control this). It could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30324 ... If not -- try finding a better one or submit your own: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=if%20align%20%23%7BPHP%20Formatter%7D%20

Comment: Other than that: why not use an external formatter instead in both editors (`Settings/Preferences  | PHP | Quality Tools` in PhpStorm) ? From the next 2024.1 version (currently in EAP stage), PhpStorm should be able to disable own formatter and only use the external one (right now it will use own one first).

Answer (score 0):

Following section of [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#51-if-elseif-else) states:

> Expressions in parentheses MAY be split across multiple lines, where each subsequent line is indented at least once. When doing so, the first condition MUST be on the next line. The closing parenthesis and opening brace MUST be placed together on their own line with one space between them. Boolean operators between conditions MUST always be at the beginning or at the end of the line, not a mix of both.

Therefore, the correct formatting of your line would be:

```php
<?php

if (
    1
    && [
        'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
    ]
) {
    // noop
}
```

- Enable Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> if() statement -> New line before first element
- Enable Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> if() statement -> New line after last element
- Enable Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Binary expressions -> Wrap if long (or chop down)